# How to call getter function inside getter function in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, getter, vuex

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { createModule } from 'vuex-toast'
import 'vuex-toast/dist/vuex-toast.css'
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    toast: createModule({
      dismissInterval: 80000
    }),
    app: {
      state: {
        raps: [],
      },
      getters: {
        getRaps () {
          return store.state.app.raps
        },
        getRapsFiltered (state, getters) { //error happens in this func
          return getters.getRaps.filter(state.filterFunc)
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

export default store
```

I got error message "Uncaught  TypeError: null is not a function".
How to call getter function inside getter?
What seems to be problem with this code?

Comment: Is `state.filterFunc` not defined?

Comment: Thanks, it was null

Answer (score 5):

You can call a getter using getters parameter passed to getter function

```
const getters = {
    calculateItemTax: () => item => {
        return item.item_tax
    },
    //pass getters as an argument and use it inside getter 
    orderTax: (state, getters) => {
        state.items.forEach(item => {
            //use getters argument to access getters functions
            taxAmount += getters.calculateItemTax(item)
        })
        return taxAmount
   },
}
```